# mapping a key so the mapping is valid only in certain application

Tags: autohotkey

*don't know if this is better suited here, or on SU - feel free to move to your liking*

Is it possible to map a key alias in autohotkey (for example, < and > to F11 and F12), but in a way that the mapping is only active while working in ... Word ?

*Not a real example of what I'm interested in, but we're talking only in principle here.*

Platform: WinXP

Answer (score 1):

```
#IfWinActive Microsoft Word
^o::
  ; Do various stuff
Return
#IfWinActive
```

Can be refined:

```
#IfWinActive BareGrep ahk_class TMainWindow
```

or

```
#IfWinActive (P4Win: Enter Password|Perforce Password Required)
```

with `SetTitleMatchMode RegEx` mode.